# Making a variable out of a interface (good or bad)?

Tags: java

I was reading in a book a while back that it is better to create your variables in your class by making them a type of the interface that your class extends. I am finding out that you can do this but if I try and call a method from the interface variable I receive and error that is listed below.

**Why do the method names show up in the smart window but then I cannot use them to call the method that I have defined?**

Why is the benefit of creating a interface variable? Does it save time later if you have to add in more methods. If you add them to the interface to the class then you would just have to call them from the variable.

Code:

```
package testpak;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class TestInterfaces implements iMyTest, iMyOwn {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void run() {
    }

    @Override
    public void myMethod() {
    }

    @Override
    public void meth1() {
        System.out.println("method 1");
    }

    @Override
    public void meth2() {
    }

    @Override
    public void meth3() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] p) {
        iMyOwn temp = null;
        temp.meth1();
    }
}

interface iMyTest extends Serializable, Runnable
{
    public void myMethod();
}

interface iMyOwn {
    public void meth1();
    public void meth2();
    public void meth3();
}
```

Error:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
  at testpak.TestInterfaces.main(TestInterfaces.java:31)
```

New Code:

```
package testpak;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class TestInterfaces implements iMyTest, iMyOwn {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void run() {
    }

    @Override
    public void myMethod() {
    }

    @Override
    public void meth1() {
        System.out.println("method 1");
    }

    @Override
    public void meth2() {
    }

    @Override
    public void meth3() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] p) {
        iMyOwn temp = new TestInterfaces();
        temp.meth1();
    }
}

interface iMyTest extends Serializable, Runnable
{
    public void myMethod();
}

interface iMyOwn {
    public void meth1();
    public void meth2();
    public void meth3();
}
```

I see what your saying now. But what benefit does this by you in programming. I have created a variable of the interface type but I used the new someClassHere() to make the variable.

```
            iMyOwn temp = new TestInterfaces();
        temp.meth1();
```

New code here:

```
package testpak;

public class TestInterfaces implements iMyOwn1, iMyOwn2 {
    @Override
    public void meth1() {
        System.out.println("method 1");
    }

    @Override
    public void meth2() {
    }

    @Override
    public void meth3() {
    }

    @Override
    public void meth4() {
    }

    @Override
    public void meth5() {
    }

    @Override
    public void meth6() {
        System.out.println("method 6");
    }

    public static void main(String[] p) {
        iMyOwn1 temp1 = new TestInterfaces();
        temp1.meth1();

        iMyOwn2 temp2 = new TestInterfaces();
        temp2.meth6();
    }
}

interface iMyOwn1 {
    public void meth1();
    public void meth2();
    public void meth3();
}

interface iMyOwn2 {
    public void meth4();
    public void meth5();
    public void meth6();
}
```

So in the example above I have two interfaces that have three methods a peace. In my main if have created the following.

```
            iMyOwn1 temp1 = new TestInterfaces();
        temp1.meth1();

        iMyOwn2 temp2 = new TestInterfaces();
        temp2.meth6();
```

Each variable has access only to its own members that have to be overridden. If I had any other methods I would have to create an instance of the class to access them. The way it stands now is that if, say ten months from now I decided to go back and add some more functionality to the class. I put those methods in the iMyOwn1 interface. I implement them into my code and then. I could use them. But if I decided to change say meth1(). I changed that in the first class and then that would be all that I would have to do because everything that temp1 references is in that method. ????

Comment: I don't understand. You set iMyOwn temp = null, and on the next line you try to call it? Obviously it is null

Comment: Why would you intentionally call a method on a `null` reference?  To call such a method, you must initialize it with a concrete class that implements that interface, e.g. `iMyOwn temp = new TestInterfaces();`.

Comment: You say `iMyOwn = null`, call a method on a null object and ask why it doesn't work? Well played...

Comment: I think the thing you're missing is that you can *treat* a variable like one of it's interfaces, but you create objects as a concrete class.  So you've declared the interface, great.  That's part 1 of 3.  Now create a class that `implement`s the interface (part 2 of 3), and then make an instance of that class using the `new` keyword (3 of 3).

Comment: Compiler said that I had to do this or it was giving me an error.

Comment: This is a good question. I have been wondering for some time why a person would make a variable of type interface and the have to use new someClass. I think I could use more of an explanation for this. Can someone post up an answer with some simple code. I think that this is a very good question.

Comment: Let me ask. What is the benefit for using the interface as the variable type? I think I see why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can define the variable of interface type.This variable can hold any class that implements this interface. It can be use full and it leads you to make agile applications. For example let s say you want to create some class that is responsible for accesing some data base. At the begining of your project your class was using just plain text files to store your information but yout project has become bigger and you want to use RDBMS. But in you code you are already use `XMLDateObject` what should you do ? Just implement new class `DBClass` and replase  all entries `XMLDateObject`? what if you have 1000 source files? in case if you used interface variable you just can get the new  'DBClass' instance assign it to your interface variable and you need nothing to change in your rest of code.
Sorry for english i learned English from dirty films:)

Comment: That is what I was looking for. So if I have a class that implements an interface of a couple of interfaces I would be better off make the instance that of the interface rather than the class. i will put up another example here in the next hour or so.

Answer (score 1):

The *type* can be an interface, but the *instance* still needs to be a class.  What the interface does is ensure that the instance is of any class which implements that interface.  So while you've set your type, you didn't create an instance.  The error you're getting has nothing to do with interfaces and everything to do with trying to use a `null` reference.

In this case you'd instantiate your variable (of the interface type) to the concrete type which implements the interface.  Something like this:

```
iMyOwn temp = new TestInterfaces();
temp.meth1();
```

Don't think of an interface as any kind of replacement for a class.  Just as a contract which any class can satisfy.  Your actual objects still need to be instances of some class, they can just be treated as instances of any interface they satisfy.